# debug netlink messages using nlmon devices

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, netlink

How do you create a nlmon device? Is it supported?

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-42-generic
$ cat /boot/config-4.10.0-42-generic | grep NLMON
CONFIG_NLMON=m
$ modprobe nlmon
modprobe: FATAL: Module nlmon not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic
```

Comment: try make modules_install which will copy ko file to /lib/modules

Comment: i cant recompile on my setup..but thanks i thought this module came as part of standard linux.